# cannot use func literal (type func(string, string, echo.Context) bool) as type middleware.BasicAuthValidator in argument to middleware.BasicAuth

Tags: api, go, go-echo

I want to apply Basic authentication in golang using echo framework. I have following error :

"# command-line-arguments

.\main.go:44:29: cannot use func literal (type
func(string, string, echo.Context) bool) as type middleware.BasicAuthValidator in argument to
middleware.BasicAuth"

my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
    "net/http"
)


// main function

func main(){
    e := echo.New()

    g := e.Group("/home")

    g.Use(middleware.BasicAuth(func (username, password string, c echo.Context) bool {
        if(username=="iamsns" && password=="Iamsns355@"){
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    
    }))

    g.POST("/login", getHome)
    

    e.Start(":8008")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs [middleware.BasicAuthValidator](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/labstack/echo/v4@v4.6.1/middleware#BasicAuthValidator) is defined as `func(string, string, echo.Context) (bool, error)` not `func(string, string, echo.Context) bool`. You need to change the signature to also return an `error`.